# Prove that every finite set is a subset of another finite set.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I know that a subset of a finite set is finite and that can be proved by induction. But how do I prove that every finite set is a subset of another finite set?

Comment: Every set is a subset of itself.

Comment: How about considering its power set

Comment: @CanTurkun Most sets aren't subsets of their powerset... There's a canonical embedding $S\to\mathcal P(S)$ given by $x\mapsto\{x\}$, but that doesn't mean $S\subset\mathcal P(S)$.

Comment: If the second set must be different from the first, just add a potato to the first set.

Comment: @Michael how do you know that "a potato" is not an element of the first set?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 : In that case you can forget the potato and add ice cream.  There is always room for ice cream.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a finite set, we have

$A \subsetneq A \cup \{A\}, \tag 1$

noting that

$A \notin A, \tag 2$

by the axiom of regularity.

We have

$\vert A \cup \{A\} \vert = \vert A \vert + 1 < \infty, \tag 3$

that is,   $A \cup \{A\}$ is finite.

Comment: Should perhaps point out that $A \notin A$ follows from the [Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_set_is_an_element_of_itself).

Comment: I wonder if there is a proof that works in anti-foundational set theory.

Comment: @Jair Taylor: done!  I didn't remember the name of that axiom 'til you reminded me!  Cheers!

Comment: @QthePlatypus Sure, look at my answer.  Wikipedia notes "Virtually all results in the branches of mathematics based on set theory hold even in the absence of regularity"

Answer (score 3):

Any set $A$ satisfies $A \subseteq A$, but let's assume you require $A$ to be a proper subset.

By the Axiom of Infinity there is an infinite set $S$. Then for any finite set $A$, we cannot have $S \subseteq A$, because as you note, a subset of a finite set is finite.  So there is some $x \in S$ with $x \notin A$.  Then $A \subsetneq A \cup \{x\}$.

Alternately, if you do not like infinite sets but you know cardinal arithmetic: let $|A| = n$ and consider $S = \{1,2, \ldots, n+1\}$.  We cannot have $S \subseteq A$, because then $n+1 = |S| \leq |A| = n$.  So again, there is some $x \in S$ with $x \notin A$.  Then $A \subsetneq A \cup \{x\}$.

Comment: I like this.  I was just about to post something like this as a proof that doesn't depend on the axiom of regularity.

Comment: Ah, I beat you to it then :)  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

With any finite set you can construct a set $S' = S \cup \{S\} $ which $S$ is a proper subset of.

Comment: This is assuming that $S\notin S$ which requires assuming the axiom of regularity.